# Comparing two DVDs

Tags: dvd

How to compare two DVDs? I mean really a binary comparison?

The problem: I have two DVDs containing a program, which should be the same. But I suspect one DVD to be modified. The sizes of the files and folders are the same, which does not mean that the content should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try VBinDiff (Visual Binary Diff)

> VBinDiff (Visual Binary Diff) displays files in hexadecimal and ASCII
>   (or EBCDIC). It can also display two files at once, and highlight the
>   differences between them. Unlike diff, it works well with large files
>   (up to 4 GB).
>
> The single-file mode was inspired by the LIST utility of 4DOS and
>   friends. While less provides a good line-oriented display, it has no
>   equivalent to LIST’s hex display. (True, you can pipe the file through
>   hexdump, but that’s incredibly inefficient on multi-gigabyte files.)<sup>[VBindiff](http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/)</sup>

To download and more info visit [VBindiff](http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/), and [Github](https://github.com/madsen/vbindiff)

Comment: Hello Mitch, thanks for the answer. But if the files are modified in that way that md5sum is the same.. I guess it will not work?

Comment: If the md5sum matches the files are exactly the same. Only permissions and times could be different. Okay, there is a theoretical chance to hit a hash-collision but I think you can ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Insert and mount the first DVD
2. Open a Terminal
3. Type `cd ${PATH_OF_YOUR_DVD_MOUNT_POINT}` (replacing ${PATH_OF_YOUR_DVD_MOUNT_POINT} with the path of the DVD mount point)
4. Type `find . -type f -exec md5sum \{\} \; >/tmp/md5sums.txt` and wait until it finishes (may take a while)
5. Type `cd` to return to the home directory
6. Unmount and eject your DVD
7. Insert and mount the second DVD
8. Again type `cd ${PATH_OF_YOUR_DVD_MOUNT_POINT}` (replacing the mount point of the second DVD this time)
9. Type `md5sum --check --quiet /tmp/md5sums.txt` and observe the output

You will get a list of files which were NOT binarily equivalent.

**NOTE**: Added correction from user [Germar](https://askubuntu.com/users/37580/germar) which for some reason was no accept in peer review.

Comment: Command from point 4 will fail on filenames that contain spaces.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki This works fine, even for filenames containing spaces. For each found file, [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/)'s `-exec` action substitutes its path as a single word (i.e., without word splitting) in place of `{}`. Even if the name contains whitespace, it's passed to the command being executed (which in this case is `md5sum`) as a single argument. [*Here's what it looks like, in action, handling a directory with file `foo bar` without a hitch.*](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8284532/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular `cmp`.

If the DVD is meant to be a perfect 1:1 copy (absolutely identical), you could compare the ISOs.

```
cmp dvd1.iso dvd2.iso
```

Otherwise on a file by file basis

```
cd /mnt/cdrom1
find -type f -exec cmp {} /mnt/cdrom2/{} \;
```

Both commands will only print something (filename and byte offset) if there are any differences. It's a byte-by-byte comparison, no checksums involved. Note that the method with `find` here doesn't detect surplus files on cdrom2, I assume you have already ruled that out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I guess that is the easy way to do it with the iso-files :)

Answer (score 0):

Insert DVD into drive and wait until Ubuntu auto-mounts it then go into directory where DVD is mounted:

```
$ cd /media/barbara/mydvd
```

Create a checksum file that contains checksums of all files on DVD:

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha1sum > /tmp/mydvd.sha1
```

Note, that above command properly handle filenames with spaces. Next, replace the DVD with the second one, and check against just created checksums:

```
$ sha1sum -c /tmp/myiso.sha1
```

If there is difference, sha1sum will print an error message about it.